# Sum based on dates on multiple column in Excel

Tags: excel

1 st column date and 2nd column amount 3rd column date and 4th column amount .. is going on.
I want to sum based on date, If date between 2019 to 2020, i need sum the amount.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the function `SUMPRODUCT` to work, assuming I understand what you want to do. (I think you want a billings total for each year, is that right?)

See [this ExcelJet article](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) on `SUMPRODUCT`.

There's probably a way to make this even shorter, but here's one solution:

[See screen clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXYFV.png) (I'm not allowed to post images yet.)

Formula for cell C6: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(B$3:B$4)=2019),C$3:C$4)`
Copy that into cells E6, G6, I6, K6, and M6. The column references will adjust.
This will give you the 2019 totals for each of the 6 periods in row 6.

Formula for cell C7: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(B$3:B$4)=2020),C$3:C$4)`
Copy that into cells E7, G7, I7, K7, and M7. The column references will adjust.
This will give you the 2020 totals for each of the 6 periods in row 7.

Formula for cell N6: `=SUM(B6:M6)`. This is the 2019 total (the sum of row 6).

Formula for cell N7: `=SUM(B7:M7)`. This is the 2020 total (the sum of row 7).